# Java: build method tree in text format and detect missing timings

Tags: java

I have a Java class that will build a method tree with timings for a log file like:

```
TIMER: method1 - Begin
... [verbose stuff] ...
TIMER: method2 - Begin
... [verbose stuff] ...
TIMER: method3 - Begin
... [verbose stuff] ...
TIMER: method3 - End [1ms]
... [verbose stuff] ...
TIMER: method2 - End [2ms]
... [verbose stuff] ...
TIMER: method1 - End [3ms]
```

The output is something like:

```
method1
  method2
   method3
   method3 [1ms]
  method2 [2ms]
method1 [3ms]
```

Basically it builds a Java method tree from a timer trace of my application so it's easy to visualize the method structure and timings. I have this working nicely and all except when there is a method who is missing a Begin or End tag in the trace. This is due to a bug in the application but I would still like my analyzer to work. Right now it builds the tree but the indentation gets messed up with missing tags (missing End tags are common, not so much the Begin).

Here is what I have and I'm not really sure how to detect if a tag is missing. Could someone please give some advice?

```
while (((line = br.readLine()) != null)) {
  if (line.contains(threadString) && line.contains("TIMER")) {

    int startMethod = line.indexOf(parseString) + parseString.length();
    int endMethod = line.indexOf(" - ", startMethod);
    String method = line.substring(startMethod, endMethod);

    int startBeginEnd = line.indexOf(" -", endMethod) + 3;
    int endBeginEnd = line.indexOf(" ", startBeginEnd);
    String beginEnd = line.substring(startBeginEnd, endBeginEnd);

    if (beginEnd.equalsIgnoreCase("Begin")) {
      System.out.println(tabs + method);
      tabs = tabs + "   ";
    }
    else if (beginEnd.equalsIgnoreCase("End")) {
      tabs = tabs.substring(0, tabs.length() - 3);
      int startTime = line.indexOf("[", endBeginEnd) + 1;
      int endTime = line.indexOf("]", startTime);
      String time = line.substring(startTime, endTime);
      System.out.println(tabs + method + " [" + time + "] ms");
      previousMethod = method;
    }

  }

}
```

EDIT:

Here's an example of the actual log:

```
2014-03-12 10:17:04,628:TIMER  :Thread-27_Agent_0: method3 - Begin                                     [system]: Class1       
2014-03-12 10:17:04,628:VERBOSE:Thread-27_Agent_0: Parameters:Code=TESTER                           [system]: Class1       
2014-03-12 10:17:04,629:TIMER  :Thread-27_Agent_0: method3 - End -  [1]                                [system]: Class1       
2014-03-12 10:17:04,629:VERBOSE:Thread-27_Agent_0: Class2- No Parameters                                [system]: Class2           
2014-03-12 10:17:04,629:VERBOSE:Thread-27_Agent_0: Parameters:::TESTER:Projectors:EACH::                   [system]: Class2           
2014-03-12 10:17:04,629:TIMER  :Thread-27_Agent_0: method1 - Begin                           [system]: Class4                 
2014-03-12 10:17:04,629:VERBOSE:Thread-27_Agent_0: Parameters::TESTER                                           [system]: Class4                 
2014-03-12 10:17:04,629:TIMER  :Thread-27_Agent_0: method1 - End -  [0]                      [system]: Class4                 
2014-03-12 10:17:04,629:TIMER  :Thread-27_Agent_0: method2 - Begin                                     [system]: Class3          
2014-03-12 10:17:04,629:TIMER  :Thread-27_Agent_0: method3 - Begin                                     [system]: Class1       
2014-03-12 10:17:04,629:VERBOSE:Thread-27_Agent_0: Parameters:                                                  [system]: Class1       
2014-03-12 10:17:04,629:VERBOSE:Thread-27_Agent_0: Parameters:blank: : :true            [system]: Class1       
2014-03-12 10:17:04,629:VERBOSE:Thread-27_Agent_0: returning rules for key [system]: Class1       
2014-03-12 10:17:04,629:TIMER  :Thread-27_Agent_0: method3 - End -  [0]                                [system]: Class1       
2014-03-12 10:17:04,629:DEBUG  :Thread-27_Agent_0: parameter is activated                                     [system]: Class3          
2014-03-12 10:17:04,630:TIMER  :Thread-27_Agent_0: method2 - End -  [1]                                [system]: Class3          
2014-03-12 10:17:04,630:TIMER  :Thread-27_Agent_0: method4 - Begin
```

Comment: Is missing whole line with method, or it only does not contain "BEGIN" or "END" at the end of line? Show us example of log, which is not well written.

Comment: I've added a real example of the log. The problem is mainly that not all the methods have an "End" tag even though they should. So when building the tree, the indentation is not correct. There could be a case where there is no "Begin" tag but that is far less common.

Comment: I added working example, if you do not have recursion there.

Answer (score 0):

If there are not same methods in same method, there is easy solution with `Map`.

This method:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Boolean> map = new HashMap<>();
        String whatItIs;
        String[] inputs = {"method1", "method1", "method1", "method2", "method3", "method3", "method2", "method1"};
        int nested = 0;        

        for (String methodname : inputs) {
            if (map.get(methodname) == null) {
                whatItIs = "BEGIN";
                nested++;
                map.put(methodname, true);
            } else {
                whatItIs = "END";
                map.remove(methodname);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < nested; i++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            System.out.println(methodname + whatItIs);

            if (whatItIs.equals("END")){
                nested--;
            }
        }

    }
```

Has this output :

```
 method1BEGIN
 method1END
 method1BEGIN
  method2BEGIN
   method3BEGIN
   method3END
  method2END
 method1END
```